# Howto install the latest CodeLite in openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, codelite

Hi I've tried to install the latest codelite but when I try to open it, it doesn't.  I followed the instructions on the site but no luck.

I'm using openSUSE 13.2 64-bit

Comment: We need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the wxWidgets runtime libs, which were supposed to be included in the CodeLite package but weren't.

openSUSE don't seem to have a meta-package for these, and there are a confusing number of choices, most of which will be wrong for you. However if you ask yast to install libwx_gtk2u_webview-suse-3_0-0 I think you'll find that will depend on the rest of the correct libwx* family.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, you can install codelite and wxwidget in opensuste in a straightforward method. Just go to the 
[opensuse software repository](https://software.opensuse.org) and search for codelite. After representation of the results press on the button

> Direct Install

to let you install the package on your machine.